# Passing lambdas as C function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, lambda

I'm working on a C++ class that passes captureless lambdas to a C library.  I'd like to remove some boilerplate, and the lambdas are all very similar (they find an instance of a class and invoke different methods that all take a single int parameter).  I created a template function:

```
typedef unsigned char (Foo::*FooMemPtr)(int ch);

template<typename Fn>
tuple<const char*, const char*, Fn> createEditLineCommandDescriptor(const char* command, const char* helpText, const FooMemPtr callback) {
  return make_tuple(command, helpText, [] (EditLine*, int ch) {
    Foo foo;
    ((&foo)->*callback)('a');
    return ch;
  });
}
```

When I compile this I get an error about the lambda trying to implicitly capture `callback`, which makes sense.  I'm wondering, since I'm in a template, and `createEditLineCommandDescriptor` is called with constant address-of-member-function parameters, is there any way to have the compiler generate the lambda when it's instantiating the template without trying to capture the parameter in C++11?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make `callback` template parameter, and specify template argument instead of passing function argument when calling `createEditLineCommandDescriptor`. E.g.

```
template<typename Fn, FooMemPtr callback>
tuple<const char*, const char*, Fn> createEditLineCommandDescriptor(const char* command, const char* helpText) {
  return make_tuple(command, helpText, [] (EditLine*, int ch) {
    Foo foo;
    ((&foo)->*callback)('a'); // or (foo.*callback)('a');
    return ch;
  });
}
```

Comment: Probably `((&foo)->*` -> `(foo.*` (unless `Foo` overloads `operator&`).